# How to convert this line with numbers to a list?

Tags: list, line

I have this
"208 Wars 209 Xevious 210 Zooming Secrataries 211 Argus 212 DR PLUMBER 213 Goonies 214 KAGE LEGEND 215 Super Chinese 216 TWIN BEE 01 217 Star Soldier 218 BALLOON monster 219 TRACK FIELD 220 80 days"

Its a list of games and as you can see each game has number in front of it starting with 208 up to 220, I would manually have to go trough the list of 500 games and hit ENTER in front of each number to put it into a new line.

**Can I somehow do this automatically ?**
With any program, is fine with me.Notepad++, maybe Word,...

Comment: you need a regex to find out all numbers. You would need text editors which support regex.

Answer (score 0):

With Word, to insert *ENTER in front of each number* with three digits, search `<[0-9]{3}>` and replace all with `^l^&` (line break followed by the found text) with pattern matching using the placeholders option.
Note that this fails if a game name contains a 3-digit number.